# Is "I was slept when he came back... " grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, adjectives, passive-voice, transitivity

> I **was** **slept** when he **came** back to the home.

The above statement has three verbs in the past tense.

- was = is
- slept = sleep
- came = come

My questions:

- Are "I was slept" and "he came back to home" grammatically correct?
- Can I use all these past tenses in a sentence like this?
- If it's correct what about the below statement?

> I **did** not go there

In this statement "did" define it is a past tense of "do"   but   "go"    never change to past tense.

So in the first example, *all* the verbs are changed into the past tense but in the second example, some verbs are not changed.

If both statements are correct, why can we use them like this?

Comment: "I was slept when he came back to the home" is grammatically incorrect. Is there any reason why you thought it might be correct? "I was sleeping when he came back to the home" would be grammatical.

Comment: You're asking (1) whether it is possible to have two verbs in the past tense in a single sentence; and (2) whether "did" takes a present or past tense verb. For (1), yes, e.g. "He *returned* after he *left*." For (2), "did" [takes a verb in its base form](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/did-main-verb-base-form-or-past-tense-form).

Comment: And “I was sleeping when he came home.” or “I was asleep when he came home.” would be idiomatic.

Comment: I am voting to migrate to ELL.

Comment: _Sleep_ is transitive in some senses, but it can't be passivized. That's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: Could you provide more information on the text you cited? Author(s)? Year/place of publication?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. http://bookstore.xlibris.com/Products/SKU-0131860049/A-Guide-To-English-Grammar.aspx

Comment: @TRomano the sweetie! She is selfless, and dedicated to the cause, but she is not a grammarian.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A.  Xlibris is a self-publishing site.

Comment: @TRomano I might delete the source if no one answers in a couple of days. The question has potential, one could give a really good in depth answer. Oh, well. as they say, beauty is in the eye of the beholder. Or in this case, "interestingness".

Comment: @If the sleep of the just would be slept by you, it would be taken down sooner rather than later.  :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA sorry I had not seen **you** had added the ref to the book. Si yes, it's better like that.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as it stands there is not correct.

This is due to the circumstance that *to sleep* is usually an intransitive verb that does not take an object. With the leading *was* the construction would be passive voice, but English doesn't use intransitive verbs that way. However, intransitive verbs can use the past continuous and thereby *was sleeping.*

> ***sleep*** *intransitive verb*
>
> to rest in a state of sleep - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep)

*Admittedly there are transitive uses of sleep, but they do not fit in the construction of the sentence in the question.*

The problem with intransitive verbs is that they don't go over into a passive voice. *I.e. you can't **be slept.*** If it was a transitive verb that took an object that would easily be understood. Take the transitive verb *to slap* for example.

> I ***was slapped*** when he came back to the home.

This sentence offers two explanations at once. Firstly it's homophone to the sentence from the original question. Thus, it might be what was spoken if the question is based on something heard.

Secondly it shows that two past tense verbs can actually be just simple past but in a passive construction.

> In the most commonly considered type of passive clause, **a form of the verb be (or sometimes get) is used as an auxiliary together with the past participle of a transitive verb**; [- Wiki: Passive Voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)
>
> A transitive verb is a verb that requires one or more objects. This contrasts with intransitive verbs, which do not have objects. Transitivity is traditionally thought of as a global property of a clause, by which activity is transferred from an agent to a patient. [- Wiki: Transitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb)

Comment: I suggest adding *usually*, so that the sentence in your answer  says 'This is due to the circumstance that to sleep is usually an intransitive verb that does not take an object.' Because as soon as I saw the sentence without *usually* I started disagreeing with your answer. And yes, I know you qualify your sentence later with 'Admittedly there are transitive uses of sleep, but they do not fit in the construction of the sentence in the question', but to me you should make clear from the beginning that *sleep* can be used transitively.

Comment: @AlanCarmack thank you for that comment. I added the word. I agree that it makes the answer better by not implying that it is always intransitive.

Comment: Not being able to passivize a measure expression or the cognate object of *sleep* is a good reason to consider them not to be real objects, and therefore not true transitive uses of the verb.  By the way, learners may run into the BrE construction *He was stood on the corner* and find this Q&A, so I wonder if it might not be appropriate to address that here.

Comment: @Laure visit the edit history, and see that the original questions are intact, the questions have been formatted properly, I only added  this one: *Are "I was slept" and "he came back to home" grammatically correct?* Which didn't veer from the OP's request too much. The book entry/image I found myself online, TRomano's comments convinced me that I was doing anyone any favours, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

"I was slept when he came back to the home" is not grammatically correct.

Let's analyze this by first breaking apart the sentence into its two clauses: "I was slept" and "he came back to the home", which are joined by "when", a subordinating conjunction.

One can *hear* instantly that the former clause is incorrect, and that the latter is correct.

"I was slept" has a subject followed by two verbs, "was" and "slept". These are the conjugated forms of the verbs "to be" and "to sleep".

'Being' verbs (including "to be", "to feel", "to seem", etc.) are often followed by an adjective or a noun which describe the object that is 'being'—does that make sense? These nouns and adjectives are called 'subject-complement-nouns' and '-adjectives', respectively.

"I was slept" needs to be "I was asleep" or "I was sleeping" because an SC-N or SC-A is needed—not a verb.

**Also,**

If we consider to sleep to be a transitive verb, then the sentence is a passive construction with no agent expressed/no object. You can read more about transitive verbs [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/transitive_verbs.html). *To sleep* can be a transitive verb, but only in special idioms, and even then it cannot be transposed to the passive ([src](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277213/is-the-verb-sleep-transitive-or-intransitive) + deadrat). Hence, in this particular case, this is not a possibility.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well  it's grammatically correct if we consider *to sleep* a transitive verb, and thus the sentence is a passive construction with no agent expressed. The likelihood of this being the case is  next to none  but not impossible.

Comment: Well, the two of can hear it instantly, but the OP, perhaps not so much.  But it's a good answer as far as it goes (that a predicate adjective or noun would make the clause grammatical). Alan notes the second possibility, that the auxiliary signals a passive construction, which is impossible with a non-transitive verb like *sleep*. May I suggest expanding your answer to include both analyses.

Comment: @deadrat, I have made an edit (the last paragraph). Does it seem 100% right to you?

Comment: If you'll forgive the editor in me, I'd say "*To sleep* can be a transitive verb, but only in special idioms, and even then it cannot be transposed to the passive." But I'm happy enough with the answer to upvote it.

Comment: @deadrat, hopefully it reads better/is more accurate now.

Comment: Actually, there are good reasons to consider measure expressions and certain cognate objects not to be real objects, and therefore not to consider verbs that take them (like *sleep*) transitive.  Passivization being impossible is one of those good reasons. But I upvoted, even though I'd say *sleep* is probably best considered intransitive in the examples the commenters have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> "I was slept when he came back to the home."

No you can not use the words as you have as the sentence does not make sense.

The problem you have is the verb sleep you have used is in the wrong form.

You can not use 'slept' to refer to the past continuous as you have here. Slept is for the present perfect tense, or past perfect tense.

For help learning the various conjugations of the verb sleep, see here: 
[Conjugations of the verb sleep](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-sleep.html)

Pay particular attention to the examples they provide and note that all the examples with *was* or *were* take the past continuous form, 'sleeping'.

You have two options to fix the sentence.

(1) use sleeping instead of slept. (see above for reference)

(2) use asleep instead of slept. [(see here)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/asleep)

> "I was asleep when he came back to the home."
>
> "I was sleeping when he came back to the home."

If you wanted to use the past perfect 'slept' you would remove 'was' from the sentence instead like this:

> "I slept when he came back to the home."

Comment: This answer really doesn't address the error, which is to use a form of the verb *to be* (namely, *was*) as an auxiliary with *slept*. This combination signals a passive construction, which is impossible with a non-transitive verb like *sleep*. A third option is simply to drop the word *was*. Please consider editing your answer.

Comment: @deadrat "My question is, Can I use all these past tense in 1 sentence like this? If it's correct that about the below statement." My answer explicitly answers the question. No you can not because you can not use the past perfect conjugation of sleep with the word was as he has. I have explained why, and provided the solution that fixes the sentence, no edit is needed. I have already suggested dropping the word was if he wants to keep the past perfect form of sleep before your comment.

Comment: 1. You haven't explained why; you've merely made an assertion. 2. You've now given three options while asserting that there are two. 3. I'm sorry that I didn't see your addition while I was writing my comment. 4. Your third of two options is the simple past, not the past perfect. 5. You could have spent your time crafting a better answer instead of defending the one you've got. 6. I'm not the site police. I haven't even downvoted your answer. I asked you to consider improving your answer. If you've decided to reject that suggestion, it max nixt to me.